# iterator/generator to produce all possible cases in a control system

Tags: python, python-3.x

python newbie here. I'm writing the code to control an experiment that has multiple variables. The variables are defined in a csv file something like:

```
Temp, Voltage, Pressure
23, 4.8, 19
23;28, 4.8, 19;23
```

I read the file and create a dictionary, that part works ok. for example the first line will be:

```
{'Temp': ['23'], 'Voltage': ['4.8'], 'Pressure': ['19']}
```

and that will control a single experiment.
The second line will be:

```
{'Temp': ['30', '28'], 'Voltage': ['4.8'], 'Pressure': ['19', '23']}
```

What I would like is a way to generate all the possible dictionaries, in sequence, from that line. For example the second line will be expanded to four experiments:

```
{'Temp': ['30'], 'Voltage': ['4.8'], 'Pressure': ['19']}
{'Temp': ['30'], 'Voltage': ['4.8'], 'Pressure': ['23']}
{'Temp': ['28'], 'Voltage': ['4.8'], 'Pressure': ['19']}
{'Temp': ['28'], 'Voltage': ['4.8'], 'Pressure': ['23']}
```

The order is important (the last column is the inner loop). I have a list with the keys in the order I want to iterate. For example:

```
('Temp', 'Voltage', 'Pressure')
```

in this case.

This is an oversimplification and there is a big number of variables (columns) in the system.

I'm thinking about a parallel dictionary with counters to keep track of the possible cases and current case for each variable, but maybe I'm missing a more elegant way to express this in python.

Regards,

--ga

Comment: I suspect `itertools.product()` can be used here: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools#itertools.product

Comment: @ThomasK it looks more like an answer than comment

Comment: @0xc0de: It's not really complete enough for an answer. AdamKG has written a more complete description, but it still needs expanding to cope with the arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: Speaking of columns: it might be easier not to put the variables in dictionaries at first, because you need them in a known order to use `product()` (and dictionaries are unordered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, you want [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). You just need to extract the lists from the dict & re-wrap the results with your dictionary structure.

```
from itertools import product
def _combinations_for_record(d):
    for tmp, vlt, prs in product(d['Temp'], d['Voltage'], d['Pressure']):
        yield {"Temp": [tmp], "Voltage": [vlt], "Pressure": [prs]}
```

Comment: thanks, this is what i needed. Since i have many parameters i need to change it a bit so i don't have to hard code the parameters in the function.